# Javascript/Ajax/jQuery/SQL User Login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a system, where at one Computer/Monitor more than 1 user can be logged in.

First the user log in. This is already working. Then it shows the username which is logged in.

When an other user log in, it shows the second User also.

So far, so good.

But the whole page is reloaded. I want to reload only the part of the Website which has to be updated (the part where it is shown).

So my question is, how can I update only the Part of the website and which programmer speech I have to use.

The Users which are logged in are saved in a $_SESSION variable - not in the database.

Here is my Code:

in **index.php** (Session is started)
`

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div  class="container" id="content">
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" id="formular">
        <a href="../Startseite/index.html" onclick="document.getElementById('back').id = 'backSpin'; document.getElementById('backLink').click(); return false" id="backLink"><img src="../back.png" style="width: 10%;" id="back"/></a>
        <b><h1 align="center">Login</h1></b>
            <form action="php/login.php" method="post" style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 70%;margin: auto; margin-top: 2%;" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required/>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 70%;margin: auto; margin-top: 2%;" id="pwd" name="passwort" placeholder="passwort" required/>
                <input type="submit" value="Login"  style="padding-left: 10%; padding-right: 10%; margin-top: 2%;" class="btn btn-warning"/>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:1%" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6" id="teamRot">
        <h1 align="center">Team Rot</h1>
        <?php
        echo $_SESSION['username1'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $_SESSION['username2'];

        ?>
    </div>
    <div  class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" id="teamBlau">
        <h1 align="center">Team Blau</h1>
        <?php
            echo $_SESSION["username3"];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo $_SESSION["username4"];
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<br/>

     <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 btn btn-warning" id="start" >
         <a href="../Spiel/index.html"  style="text-decoration: none; color: black"  ><h1 align="center" >start</h1></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

`

in login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include "../../connector.php";


$username = $_POST['username'];
$passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

echo $_SESSION["zaehler"];



$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username FROM Spieler WHERE passwort=? AND  username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $passwort, $username);
//mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $passwort);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ergebnis);
$stmt->fetch();

$stmt->close();

if($ergebnis == null)
{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    echo "var checK = alert('Username oder Passwort falsch');
    if (!checK)
    {
        history.go(-1); // go back since user clicked cancel
    }";

    echo "</script>";
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["zaehler"]=$_SESSION["zaehler"] + 1;
    if($_SESSION["zaehler"] == 1)
    {    $_SESSION["username1"]= $ergebnis;}
    elseif($_SESSION["zaehler"] == 2)
    {    $_SESSION["username2"]= $ergebnis;}
    elseif($_SESSION["zaehler"] == 3)
    {    $_SESSION["username3"]= $ergebnis;}
    elseif($_SESSION["zaehler"] == 4)
    {    $_SESSION["username4"]= $ergebnis;}
    elseif($_SESSION["zaehler"] == 5)
        session_destroy();


   header("Location:../index.php");
}
```

Comment: Best way is use ajax .....

Comment: From where your getting session variable.

Comment: I get the username over the $_POST variable and store it into a $_SESSION variable.

Comment: and this $_SESSION variable is printed with "echo" into a div.

Comment: So do one thing whenever updating using $_SESSION variable at the same time in the  "echo" into a div.

Comment: can you show me your post request

Comment: Okay, I use echo to print this variable. But how can I forward the output to a certain div? I mean to a div which is already declared at the "index" side.

Comment: can you show your code here and posr request as well

Comment: You need to append variable  to that div.

Comment: I have done it I hope you know now the problem and give me an code example if you know a solution. if not, thank you anyway